# hashtable constructor performance in java

Tags: java, performance, hashtable

I was working on [a coding problem on codeeval](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/106/) using Java, in which I used hashtable to store the fundamental mappings for converting cardinal numbers to roman numbers as below:

```
{1: 'I', 5: 'V', 10: 'X', 50: 'L', 100: 'C', 500: 'D', 1000: 'M'}
```

I was trying to constructing the Hashtable with two different methods but got quite different performance results according to Codeeval's profiler. 
The first one is:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> match = new Hashtable<Integer, String>(){{
        put(1, "I");
        put(5, "V");
        put(10, "X");
        put(50, "L");
        put(100, "C");
        put(500, "D");
        put(1000, "M");
        }};
```

The running time I got from Codeeval's profiler is 172 ms and used 8347648 Bytes memory space, while if I change the code to:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> match = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
        match.put(1, "I");
        match.put(5, "V");
        match.put(10, "X");
        match.put(50, "L");
        match.put(100, "C");
        match.put(500, "D");
        match.put(1000, "M");
```

The running time of the later method is 137 ms and used 8212480 Bytes memory space. All other code in the programs are the same.

Why this minor change of the code leads to so much difference? Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: The double-brace initialization technique can cause memory leaks, and generates a whole new class to load for the runtime.  It's really best avoided.  It's "cute" but a terrible idea.

Comment: Just curious.. what is the performance if you change the Hashtable to a HashMap? I ask because Hashtable is synchronized and HashMap is not. I would expect HashMap to have better performance.

Comment: @dlcole Changing HashMap make the code become slower, but thank you for your advice.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Use `switch` — it has the best performance ;)

Comment: @v.ladynev +1 for providing experienced answer. Great.

Answer (score 0):

CodeEval's profiler varies a lot between languages (and between updates of their site) as to how consistently it works -- with Java on CodeEval right now, you will see those sorts of ms and memory variations when you upload the *same* solution multiple times. For instance, I uploaded my Java solution to Roman Numerals a few times just now, and the ms scores ranged from 140 to 188, and the memory scores from 8310784 to 9158656.